# How to convert Decimal in a String Format in XAML WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How i will convert Decimal value in a String Format(Currency) in XAML WPF?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="12,2,0,2" Text="$ " />
    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="12,2,0,2" Text="{Binding p_Price}"/> 
 </StackPanel>
```

//Text="{Binding p_Price, ConverterParameter='0,0.00'}" Not Working

Comment: The ConverterParameter is intended for using with a converter. You can't use this attribute this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need two `TextBlocks`, use `StringFormat` to get the currency

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="12,2,0,2" Text="{Binding p_Price, StringFormat=C}"/> 
 </StackPanel>
```

Also, your p_Price property should not be of type `string`.

Answer (score 1):

As **Nit** suggested, you can get what you want with the Currency format (`C` or `c`).

I suggest you have a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has all the references to what you can do with it.

You can specify a number after the `c` for the amount of digits after the decimal point, and pass the region as well:

> 123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
>
> 123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €
>
> 123.456 ("C", ja-JP) -> ¥123
>
> -123.456 ("C3", en-US) -> ($123.456)
>
> -123.456 ("C3", fr-FR) -> -123,456 €
>
> -123.456 ("C3", ja-JP) -> -¥123.456

Depending on your needs, `N` might be useful as well.